# Get SQL Server database server address

Tags: sql-server

I am installing an app and I am at the point where I am supposed to provide the server details. I installed SQL Server Express and I also installed SQL Server Management Studio.

This is the screenshot:

[image]

I did execute this command

```
select @@servername
```

but I got this response:

[image]

I am running this on my local machine. How can I find the database server address and also the server password?.

PS: I do not remember setting any password when installing SQL Server.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, that `DESKTOP-KOJLCIF\SQLEXPRESS` ***is*** your SQL Server "server&instance name" - try using that in your input box

Comment: I do not remember setting any password when installing SQL Server. >> You can reset password by login using Windows Login Mode in SQL Server. There is no way to display PLAIN password.

Comment: @marc_s Where can  setup tcp login using username and password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you executed the command `select @@servername`, how were you connected to the server?  Running that command required knowing the servername and authentication of some kind.  I'm guessing you were connected to `DESKTOP-KOJLCIF\SQLEXPRESS` or `.\SQLEXPRESS` using windows authentication.

When you installed SQL Express, there was an option for Windows Authentication or SQL Server + Windows (aka Mixed Mode) Authentication.  If you chose Windows Authentication (which is the default if I recall), you will not have SQL Server usernames or passwords.

The app you are installing appears to required SQL Auth, so you need to pick Mixed Mode in your setup (which allows both Windows Auth and SQL Auth).  You can find this setting in recent versions of SQL Server Management Studio by right-clicking your database server in object explorer, going to Properties, and then looking at the Security page.  Older versions of SQL require going to another tool included in the installation folders-- server configuration or some such, the name escapes me.  Change the authentication to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".  I believe a SQL Server restart is required after doing this.

You can then create SQL logins with username and passwords and appropriate permissions using the GUI in SSMS (expand security folder under your server and look at the logins sub folder) or via CREATE LOGIN t-sql command.

There is a fixed sql login called 'sa' that will always exist if SQL Auth is enabled.  You could right click this login, go to properties, and change the password.  Be careful giving out your sa credentials to an app, as that can control the entire server.